# How to make "edit post" method available for only 10 minutes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a Instagram clone as a mini project to understand how to use Rails, which I haven't had any prior experience with. One of the "client" requirements is to be able to edit their comments on a post but only for up to 15 minutes.

I have done some research but am struggling to find the best way of implementing this feature. Is there something in Rails that would help me to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can use `created_at` with Active Record to see if the post is older than 15 minutes. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a method to check if it's editable such as:

```
def editable?
  Time.now - self.created_at < 10.minutes
end
```

It needs validation as well:

```
def validate_is_editable
  if self.persisted? && !self.editable?
    self.errors[:editable] << "can edit in just 10 minutes after creation"
  end
end
```